# Thymeleaf view error when loading the page

Tags: java, thymeleaf

I would like to ask for help about my little project I just started to study spring boot and so far I got to a point where I want to express the backend into the frontend.

So far I had a problem with the Navbar because I wanted Navbar at every page and I don't know simply how to include it properly on every HTML I create, but this isn't my problem. The problem is that I've made the same Navbar for every page that's good but when I load my `index(/)` page everything is fine I got navbar/footer but when I try to load my `/list` page I have to get a table with people from the DB like it worked before when I had Navbar only on index page but now when I try to load the page I got this.error:

> [THYMELEAF][http-nio-8080-exec-10] Exception processing template
>   "base-layout": Error resolving template [list/people], template might
>   not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template
>   Resolvers (template: "base-layout" - line 5, col 7)

I will paste the problematic my code In the bottom so you can try to help me if possible

This is my `PersonController` which have to return the list of people

```
@RequestMapping("/list")
  public String listPeople(Model model){
    List<Person> personList = personService.getAllPersons();

    model.addAttribute("people", personList);
    model.addAttribute("view", "list/people");

    return "base-layout";
  }
```

this is my `base-layout.html`:

```
<head th:include="fragments/head" th:with="pageTitle='Web in progress'"></head>

<body>
<header th:include="fragments/header"></header>
<main th:include="${view}"></main>
<footer th:include="fragments/footer"></footer>
<span th:include="fragments/scripts-bundle"></span>
</body>
```

I've expected to get my Navbar working on every page and my people table to load if you can people show me where is my error so I can continue into developing my project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

may be your problem raise form this line--

```
    model.addAttribute("view", "list/people");
```

according your code ..you have a `people` fragment under `list` folder . like this

```
--->main
    -->java
    -->resources
       -->templates
          -->fragments
          -->list // may be you miss this folder
            |_people.html
```

Comment: This fixed my error the problem was that i didn’t had the folder “list”.Thank you that solves my issue